# Symfony Form Validation does not work for nested forms?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have UserType form with embed ProfileType. Profile entity (1:1 to User) has Validation Constraints defined in validation.yml. If I send invalid data and then call:

```
if ($form->isValid())
```

it returns true. Same happens if I call validation manually:

```
if (empty($this->get('validator')->validate($form->getData()))
```

it also returns true. However, if I validate only profile:

```
if (empty($this->get('validator')->validate($form->getData()->getProfile()))
```

now it returns false, so it works correctly, and even it returns expected validation messages! What am I doing wrong?

I can provide code samples if needed.

Comment: How does the validation metadata for your `User` class look like? Did you configure it to expect the embedded `Profile` instance to be valid?

Comment: I don't have validation metadata for User since there is nothing to validate, only for Profile

Comment: Well, there is. You want the embedded `Profile` object to be valid. So at least you should add the [Valid](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) validation constraint to the `profile` property of your `User` class.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that :)